# How to set a DEFINE variable equal to the selection from another defined table in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

How can I use the DEFINE function to set a variable which is equal to the result of another SELECT statement?  (the result being only a single-column/single-row selection)

Example:

```
DEFINE source_table = mysourcetable
DEFINE use_date = select distinct max(txn_date) from &source_table

select asdf1, asdf2
from &source_table s
where &use_date between s.eff_date and s.end_date
```

The error I'm currently getting is 'missing expression' on the &usedate variable in the WHERE clause.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out. The &use_date in the WHERE clause needs to be put in parenthesis...

```
DEFINE source_table = mysourcetable
DEFINE use_date = select distinct max(txn_date) from &source_table

select asdf1, asdf2
from &source_table s
where (&use_date) between s.eff_date and s.end_date
```

***OR*** put the DEFINE query in parenthesis:

```
DEFINE source_table = mysourcetable
DEFINE use_date = (select distinct max(txn_date) from &source_table)

select asdf1, asdf2
from &source_table s
where &use_date between s.eff_date and s.end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, this is another way using the `COLUMN .. NEW_VALUE` command :

```
DEFINE source_table = mysourcetable

column  the_col new_value  use_date 

select distinct max(txn_date) the_col from &source_table;

PROMPT The value is &use_date 

select asdf1, asdf2
from &source_table s
where TO_DATE('&use_date') between s.eff_date and s.end_date;
```